# Why is my SQL query not returning results?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get a form on my site to work. Here are the tables in the database it's referencing:

USERS TABLE

| userID | Object1 | Object2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1abc | 123a |
| 2 | 2def | 123b |

POSTS TABLE

| ID | Object2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 123a |
| 43 | 123b |

The form takes a manually entered key. When I hit submit, it's supposed to run this function:

```
public function claim(Request $request){

      $post = "SELECT posts.id FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON users.Object2=posts.Object2 WHERE   posts.is_deleted='No' && users.Object1=$request->'Object1'";
      $result = mysql_query($post);
      
      if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                
            return 1;
      }
      else{
         return 0;
      }
   }
```

The problem is, when I click submit, the form doesn't do anything. No result, no error message. The form is supposed to take the manually entered "Object1", find the associated "Object2", check the Posts table for entries that have that "Object2" and spit out a result.

I've tried running the query in phpMyAdmin and replaced `"users.Object1=$request->'Object1'"` with `"users.Object1='1abc'"` and it gives me the correct result which is "12". Yet when I try putting it in my php file for my site, the form does nothing.

EDIT:

Here is the code that is running the form:

```html
$.ajax({
            url: "http://*********",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {key},
            success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
           if(response == 1){
            $('.message').text('Success')
            $('.message').removeClass('text-danger')
            $('.message').addClass('text-success')
            $('#pdf').show();
            $('#button').hide();
```

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued in PHP 5.5 (2013) and removed entirely in PHP 7 (2015). No apps should still be using it. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` (both released in the 2000s!) as soon as possible, and learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: So have you added any other debugging steps, like a `var_dump($request);` as the first line of the claim() function, to see if the function is actually called at all? How is the `claim()` function supposed to be triggered by the form? Presumably there's some other PHP code which handles this - are you using a framework of some sort? If the form does "nothing" - do you mean it doesn't even post back? Have you checked the browser's network tool to see if the form submission request is being submitted, and the payload contains what you expect, and see what response the server returns?

Comment: Have you got PHP error reporting enabled too, so you can see any syntax or runtime errors? Or at least log them to a file, if not on-screen?

Comment: P.S. `$request->'Object1'` ought to be `$request->Object1` I'd expect, there should be no need for the quote marks.

Comment: Okay I'm a complete beginner here, so I'm going to have to look up much of what you're referring to. 

I turned on the Network developer tool in the browser, clicked submit, and something popped up. jquery.min.js.

Comment: Is that in the console? You need to look in the network area for a request popping up to whatever URL is specified in your $.ajax command, it should appear at the moment you submit the form, assuming the javascript code is actually sending it correctly

Comment: Also you didn't answer about how the php function is being triggered once the server receives the request, and/or whether you use a php framework, which it looks like you might. Although the answer below may well fix the issue, it's good for you to learn how to investigate and debug these kinds of issues, and where to go to look for error messages and unexpected behaviour etc. Then you can fix problems yourself a lot more easily - if you write anything more compicated than a "hello world" program then it's important that you also understand how you can debug it when it goes wrong

Comment: I honestly don't know. My developer could not get the site to do what I need it to do, so now I'm trying to learn on the fly to make it work, and failing miserably.

Comment: OK. If you're not a developer with at least a little bit of experience you're going to struggle on this site a bit,  it's designed for programmers to help each other, so we're going to ask you for technical information. If the developer you hired is stuck, they should be the one posting questions here really, to try and help get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the single quotes in the wrong place.'

```
users.Object1=$request->'Object1'
```

should be

```
users.Object1='$request->Object1'
```

The quotes need to go around the entire string value, just like when you write it literally with `users.Object1='1abc'`.